# Monk and Power of Time DataStructure query

Tags: c, arrays, data-structures

Here is the Description of Question:
There are **N** processes to be completed by you, the chosen one, since you're Monk's favorite student. All the processes have a unique number assigned to them from **1** to **N.**

Now, you are given two things:
-The calling order in which all the processes are called. 
-The ideal order in which all the processes should have been executed.

Now, let us demonstrate this by an example. Let's say that there are **3 processes**, the calling order of the processes is: **3 - 2 - 1.** The ideal order is: **1 - 3 - 2**, i.e., process number 3 will only be executed after process number 1 has been completed; process number 2 will only be executed after process number 3 has been executed.

-***Iteration #1*:** Since the ideal order has process #1 to be executed firstly, the calling ordered is changed, i.e., the first element has to be pushed to the last place. Changing the position of the element takes 1 unit of time. The new calling order is: 2 - 1 - 3. Time taken in step #1: 1.

-***Iteration #2:*** Since the ideal order has process #1 to be executed firstly, the calling ordered has to be changed again, i.e., the first element has to be pushed to the last place. The new calling order is: 1 - 3 - 2. Time taken in step #2: 1.

-***Iteration #3*:** Since the first element of the calling order is same as the ideal order, that process will be executed. And it will be thus popped out. Time taken in step #3: 1.

-***Iteration #4*:** Since the new first element of the calling order is same as the ideal order, that process will be executed. Time taken in step #4: 1.

-***Iteration #5*:** Since the last element of the calling order is same as the ideal order, that process will be executed. Time taken in step #5: 1.
Total time taken: 5 units.

**PS:** Executing a process takes 1 unit of time. Changing the position takes 1 unit of time.

**Input format:**
The first line a number N, denoting the number of processes. The second line contains the calling order of the processes. The third line contains the ideal order of the processes.
**Output format:**
Print the total time taken for the entire queue of processes to be executed. 
**Constraints:** 
1<=N<=100

But my Output is in this way: where i have done wrong!!!!!

**Input**
3
3 2 1
1 3 2

**Your Code's Output**
  73

**Expected Correct Output**
  5

**Compilation Log**
  Compiled successfully.

```
 #include <stdio.h>
    int *move_last(int a[],int n1)
    {
        int temp,i;
        temp=a[0];
        for(i=1;i<n1;i++)
        {
            a[i-1]=a[i];
        }
        a[n1-1]=temp;
        return a;
    }
    int *remove_first(int a[],int n2)
    {
        int temp,i;
        temp=a[0];
        for(i=1;i<n2;i++)
            a[i-1]=a[i];
        return a;
    }
    int main()
    {
        //co:calling order array io:ideal order array
        //ptime:process time**strong text**
        int co[100],io[100];
        int n,i,j,count=0,ptime=0;
        scanf("%d",&n);
        for(i=0;i<n;i++)
            scanf("%d",&co[i]);
        for(i=0;i<n;i++)
            scanf("%d",&io[i]);
        while(count!=n)
        {
            while(co[0]!=io[0])
            {
                int *p;
                int size=sizeof(co)/sizeof(co[0]);
                p=move_last(co,size);
                for ( i = 0; i < size; i++ ) 
                    co[i]=*(p + i);
                ptime++;
            }
            if(co[0]==io[0])
            {
                int *p;
                int size=sizeof(co)/sizeof(co[0]);
                p=remove_first(co,size);
                size=size-1;
                for ( i = 0; i < size; i++ ) 
                    co[i]=*(p + i);
                count++;
                ptime++;
            }

        }

        printf("%d",ptime);
        `enter code here`return 0;
    }
```

Comment: For some specific input, what is the expected *and actual* output? Have you tried stepping through the code in a debugger to see that it does what you expect it to? Have you tried to [explain the code to your rubber duck](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rubber_duck_debugging)?

Comment: And by the way, if `n` is less than the number of elements in `co`, then you will use the *uninitialized* elements in `co` *anyway*. Those uninitialized elements will have *indeterminate* values.

Comment: n canncot be less than co because n is the size of initial array and by popping first element from co array makes it reduce to the value less than n but not greatet then n

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your main problem is here: `int size=sizeof(co)/sizeof(co[0]);`. You get the *declared* size of the arrays (here 100), when you only want to process the *used* size (here n=3 initially) - the correct value for size is actually `n - count`.

In addition, as `move_last` and `remove_first` actually change the array, copying it again after the function has been called is just a waste of time: you copy an array on to itself - the return value is just a pointer on first element of the initial array, C does not return arrays...

Quick fix of this is enough to get the expected value:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int *move_last(int a[],int n1)
{
    int temp,i;
    temp=a[0];
    for(i=1;i<n1;i++)
    {
        a[i-1]=a[i];
    }
    a[n1-1]=temp;
    return a;
}
int *remove_first(int a[],int n2)
{
    int temp,i;
    temp=a[0];
    for(i=1;i<n2;i++)
        a[i-1]=a[i];
    return a;
}
int main()
{
    //co:calling order array io:ideal order array
    //ptime:process time**strong text**
    int co[100],io[100];
    int n,i,j,count=0,ptime=0;
    scanf("%d",&n);
    for(i=0;i<n;i++)
        scanf("%d",&co[i]);
    for(i=0;i<n;i++)
        scanf("%d",&io[i]);
    while(count != n)
    {
        while(co[0]!=io[0])
        {
            int *p;
            int size=n - count;
            p=move_last(co,size);
            /*for ( i = 0; i < size; i++ ) 
                co[i]=*(p + i);*/
            ptime++;
        }
        if(co[0]==io[0])
        {
            int *p;
            int size=n - count;
            p=remove_first(co,size);
            remove_first(io, size);
            size=size-1;
            /*for ( i = 0; i < size; i++ ) 
                co[i]=*(p + i);*/
            count++;
            ptime++;
        }

    }

    printf("%d",ptime);
    return 0;
}
```

But there are still many possible improvements. First, you should control the return values of all scanf: currently an error in the input file will result in undefined behaviour. IMHO this is a best practice rule that will save you later from many headaches

Next `size` should be defined directly at main level and initialized to `n` before the loop, and the loop condition could then be: `while (size > 0)`, making `count` useless.

`if(co[0]==io[0])` after a `while(co[0]!=io[0])` loop is useless: if you went out of the loop, then `co[0]==io[0]` must be true.

`temp` in `remove_first` is useless: you set its value once but never use it

The values returned by `move_last` and `remove_first` are useless because they are just pointers to the first element of their input array: they could as well be void functions

Answer (score 1):

**This is the solution in java**

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.LinkedList;
import java.util.Queue;

public class Monk_and_Power_of_Time {
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException
{
    BufferedReader br=new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
    int n=Integer.parseInt(br.readLine());
    String s[]=br.readLine().trim().split(" ");
    Queue<Integer> q=new LinkedList<Integer>();
    for(int i=0;i<n;i++)
    {
        q.add(Integer.parseInt(s[i]));
    }
    String s2[]=br.readLine().trim().split(" ");
    Queue<Integer> q2=new LinkedList<Integer>();
    for(int i=0;i<n;i++)
    {
        q2.add(Integer.parseInt(s2[i]));
    }
    check(n,q,q2);

}
private static void check(int n, Queue<Integer> q, Queue<Integer> q2) 
{
    int c=0;
    while(true)
    {   if(q.peek()!=q2.peek())
        {
            int a=q.peek();
            q.remove();
            q.add(a);               
            c++;
        }
        if(q.peek()==q2.peek())
        {
            q.remove();
            q2.remove();
            c++;
        }
        if(q.isEmpty()  )
        {
            break;
        }
    }
    System.out.println(c);  
}    
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There are so many problems with your implementation, I don't know where to start....

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int pop_front(int* p, int n)
{
    int t = p[0];
    memmove(&p[0], &p[1], (n - 1) * sizeof(p[0]));
    return t;
}

void move_first_to_last(int* p, int n)         // very similar to pop_front()
{
    int t = pop_front(p, n);
    p[n - 1] = t;
}

int* load_array(char* input, int n)             // twice the same op = function + half the work.
{
    int i;
    char* p;
    int* result = (int*)malloc(n * sizeof(int));
    if (!result)
    {
        return NULL;
    }

    for (p = strtok(input, " \n"), i = 0; p != NULL && i < n; p = strtok(NULL, " \n"), ++i)
    {
        result[i] = atoi(p);
    }
    if (i != n)
    {
        free(result);
        result = NULL;
    }
    return result;
}

#define MAX_LINE_LEN (4 << 10)

int main()
{
    char* line;
    int num_tasks, iter;
    int* current_order, *desired_order;

    line = (char*)malloc(MAX_LINE_LEN);
    if (!line)
    {
        exit(1);
    }

    if (fgets(&line[0], MAX_LINE_LEN, stdin) != &line[0])
    {
        free(line);
        exit(1);
    }

    num_tasks = atoi(line);

    if (fgets(&line[0], MAX_LINE_LEN, stdin) != &line[0])
    {
        free(line);
        exit(1);
    }
    current_order = load_array(line, num_tasks);
    if (!current_order)
    {
        free(line);
        exit(1);
    }

    if (fgets(&line[0], MAX_LINE_LEN, stdin) != &line[0])
    {
        free(line);
        exit(1);
    }
    desired_order = load_array(line, num_tasks);
    if (!desired_order)
    {
        free(line);
        free(current_order);
        exit(1);
    }

    iter = 0;
    while (num_tasks)                           
    {
        ++iter;                                     // 1 task per iteration.
        if (current_order[0] == desired_order[0])
        {
            pop_front(desired_order, num_tasks);
            pop_front(current_order, num_tasks);
            --num_tasks;                           // reducing the problem as we go.
        }
        else
        {
            move_first_to_last(current_order, num_tasks);
        }
    }
    printf("%d\n", iter);

    free(current_order);
    free(desired_order);
    free(line);
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Problem : Given N processes , and the order in which they are called and the order in which they have to executed. Find the time taken to execute all of them in the execution order given.

Explanation :

Now , the solution of this problem is straight simulation , where we have to simulate as the statement dictates.

For simulating it we can use queue data structure . First push the tasks in the queue Q in the order in which they were called. Now , iterate through the queue from the front , and check whether the current process in the queue matches with the first process in the order of execution if it matches then execute it other wise send the process in the front of the queue and again repeat this process.

The pseudo code for this solution would be :

```
Q = queue containing the processes in the order they were called
time = 0
while Q is not empty :
     time = time + 1
     x = process in front of Q
     if x == current process in execution order :
            remove  x from Q
     else :
            move the x from front to the back of the Q
```

The complexity of this algorithm will be O(N2) for the worst case scenario , such as this :

Call order = 1 2 3 4 5 Execution order = 5 4 3 2 1

Time Complexity: O(N^2)

```
   #include <bits/stdc++.h>
    using namespace std;
    int main()
    {
        int N,Num;
        cin>>N;
        queue<int> Q;
        for(int i=0;i<N;i++)
        {
            cin>>Num;
            Q.push(Num);
        }
        int a[N];
        for(int i=0;i<N;i++)
            cin>>a[i];
        int total_time = 0, executed_job = 0;
        while(!Q.empty())
        {
            int job = Q.front();
            if(job == a[executed_job]){
                Q.pop();
                total_time++;
                executed_job++;
            }
            else
            {
                Q.pop();
                Q.push(job);
                total_time++;
            }
        }
        cout<<total_time<<endl;
        return 0;
    }
```

Comment: Was this question tagged as C++?

Answer (score 0):

Here is the answer in Swift 5 :

```swift
var callingOrderArr = [3,2,1]
var idealOrderArr = [1,3,2]
var counter = 0
while idealOrderArr.count > 0 {
    counter += 1
    if idealOrderArr[0] == callingOrderArr[0]{
        idealOrderArr.remove(at: 0)
    } else {
        callingOrderArr.append(callingOrderArr[0])
    }
    callingOrderArr.remove(at: 0)
 }
print(counter)
```

Comment: You should always add a few lines of explanation/reasoning to your solution. It helps others to understand your intentions especially when you have more code to cover. Sometimes there are multiple ways but you choose method-x over method-y for a good reason. Also, you can point out edge cases and the like.